# Warning: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm stuck on a simple problem. I'm trying to get all the data from the strings into one Element (like a ul).

Here is what I have tried:

```
<pre>

<?php
var_dump ($_POST);

foreach ($_POST as $user) {
enter code hereecho $user;
}

?>

</pre>
```

And this is what i get from the var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["firstUl"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Test1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Test3"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Test4"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Test5"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "Test6"
  }
}
```

I want to put each string inside a ul. I cant find a solution.

Comment: what do you mean by a?

Comment: ul i have edited the post :D

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the index for your foreach, for example :

```
foreach ($_POST as $ul) {
    foreach ($ul as $key => $user) {
        echo $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same Error Warning:  Array to string conversion in ""
But underneath of the error: array

Comment: Oh since your array is a multidimensional array, so you could do like my updated answer